# Can't generate dependent java classes from avro subjects

Tags: java, avro, maven-plugin, confluent-schema-registry

In my simple maven application I have 3 avro files:

`ReportDetails.avsc`

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ReportDetails",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "detailId", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "detailName", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

`Employee.avsc`

```
{
  "fields": [
    { "name": "employeeId", "type": "string"},
    { "name": "position", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "department", "type": "int" },
    {"name": "employeeName", "type": "string"}
  ],
  "name": "Employee",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "type": "record"
}
```

`Report.avsc`

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Report",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "reportId", "type": "string"}
    , {"name": "employee", "type": ["null", "com.vl.model.avro.Employee"], "default": null}
    , {"name": "details", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "com.vl.model.avro.ReportDetails"}}
  ]
}
```

the plugin configuration is

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                            <includes>
                                <include>ReportDetails.avsc</include>
                                <include>Employee.avsc</include>
                                <include>Report.avsc</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

### The first stage issue

so this fails because of

```
[INFO] --- avro:1.11.3:schema (default) @ spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streaming-example ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.693 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-01T14:43:20+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema (default) on project spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streaming-example: Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema failed: Undefined name: "com.vl.model.avro.Employee" -> [Help 1]
```

to make it working i updated the `Report` configuration (`Employee` and `ReportDetails` without changes)

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Report",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "reportId", "type": "string"}
    , {"name": "employee", "type": ["null", {"type": "record", "name": "Employee", "fields": []}], "default": null}
    , {"name": "details", "type": {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "record", "name": "ReportDetails", "fields": []}}}
  ]
}
```

It looks fixed my `avro:1.11.3:schema` generating issue and works fine because generates things exactly I need.

### Following next step. Share the schemas.

Avro schemas has to be registered in schema registry service for sharing on different micro services. To cover this need i've configured `kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin` (`7.5.1`), which can upload and download models.

So the plugin configuration is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>avro-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>download</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaRegistryUrls>
                        <param>http://localhost:8081</param>
                    </schemaRegistryUrls>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/avro</outputDirectory>
                    <subjectPatterns>
                        <param>^com.vl.model.*$</param>
                    </subjectPatterns>
                    <versions>
                        <param>latest</param>
                    </versions>

                    <subjects>
                        <com.vl.model.ReportDetails>src/main/resources/avro/ReportDetails.avsc</com.vl.model.ReportDetails>
                        <com.vl.model.Employee>src/main/resources/avro/Employee.avsc</com.vl.model.Employee>
                        <com.vl.model.Report>src/main/resources/avro/Report.avsc</com.vl.model.Report>
                    </subjects>
                    <schemaTypes>
                        <com.vl.model.ReportDetails>AVRO</com.vl.model.ReportDetails>
                        <com.vl.model.Employee>AVRO</com.vl.model.Employee>
                        <com.vl.model.Report>AVRO</com.vl.model.Report>
                    </schemaTypes>
                    <references>
                        <com.vl.model.Report>
                            <reference>
                                <name>details</name>
                                <subject>com.vl.model.ReportDetails</subject>
                            </reference>
                            <reference>
                                <name>employee</name>
                                <subject>com.vl.model.Employee</subject>
                            </reference>
                        </com.vl.model.Report>
                    </references>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

### Subjects registration issue

Registering schemas `mvn schema-registry:register` leads to different issue

```
[INFO] --- schema-registry:7.5.1:register (default-cli) @ spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streaming-example ---
[INFO] Registered subject(com.vl.model.Overtime) with id 3 version 1
[INFO] Registered subject(com.vl.model.Absence) with id 4 version 1
[INFO] Registered subject(com.vl.model.Employee) with id 5 version 1
[INFO] Registered subject(com.vl.model.ReportDetails) with id 6 version 1
[INFO] Registered subject(com.vl.model.Attendance) with id 7 version 1
[ERROR] Could not parse Avro schema
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: com.vl.model.avro.Employee
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.put (Schema.java:1550)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.add (Schema.java:1544)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse (Schema.java:1665)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse (Schema.java:1765)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse (Schema.java:1678)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse (Schema.java:1433)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse (Schema.java:1421)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchema.<init> (AvroSchema.java:120)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaProvider.parseSchemaOrElseThrow (AvroSchemaProvider.java:54)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:123)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:286)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (SchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.processSubject (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:120)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.execute (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR] Schema for com.vl.model.Report could not be parsed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

because we can't declare two times `"type": "record", "name": "Employee"` or `"ReportDetails"`.

### Subject registration solution

Trying to resolve the last issue I updated `Report` description

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Report",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "reportId", "type": "string"}
    , {"name": "employee", "type": {"type": "Employee", "java-class": "com.vl.model.avro.Employee"}}
    , {"name": "details", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "com.vl.model.avro.ReportDetails"}}
  ]
}
```

It is in the schema registry now.

### Different part is broken

Avro schemas definitely published to the schema registry. But neither local nor remote can't help generate java classes.
The pulled `avro` files from schema registry and you can find that they are different a little. The issue for remote schema:

```
[INFO] --- avro:1.11.3:schema (default) @ spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streaming-example ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.753 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-01T16:59:40+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema (default) on project spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streaming-example: Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema failed: "Employee" is not a defined name. The type of the "employee" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression. -> [Help 1]
```

for local schema `Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema failed: Type not supported: Employee` .

The downloaded `Report.avsc` from schema registry (I formatted one to improve readability) looks like:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Report",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "reportId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "employee",
      "type": "Employee"
    },
    {
      "name": "details",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "ReportDetails"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(missed `com.vl.model.avro` namespace before types like a `Employee`, `ReportDetails`)

### Questions

As you can see, resolving one issue we are getting different one. I'll be happy to

1. Get solution for any described issue without side effect.
2. Get an idea connected to different maven plugins to cover my needs.
3. Get a scenario to be checked that I've not checked yet.

### P.S.

I didn't removed avsc references because I sure it bring serialisation issues at kafka communication time.

P.S.2.
Solution should generate java data classes using maven builder. Java classes will be used for publishing kafka messsages.

Comment: why not "name":"employee","type":"Employee" everywhere? its the obvious thing to try

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel, where you want to, i'll provide issue details. The issue will be connected to schema registry publishing or to java class generator

Comment: ok so you passed first stage issue because you defined employee type twice, not because your schema is correct...afterwards everything goes downhill

Comment: yes. first step we can't consider as a solution, i think the last configuration looks like solution, but java class generating work until we pulled from the schema registry subjects. after that they corrupted. The namespaces of published and pulled types are different there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the correct schema pulled from schema registry (it's logical on other case nobody would use it in their projects.)

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Report",
  "namespace": "com.vl.model.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "reportId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "employee",
      "type": "Employee"
    },
    {
      "name": "details",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "ReportDetails"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So the issue might be with plugin. Verifying the plugin api, I've realised that I missed in my configuration something important.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                            <imports>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/Employee.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/ReportDetails.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/Report.avsc</import>
                            </imports>
                            <includes>
                                <include>ReportDetails.avsc</include>
                                <include>Employee.avsc</include>
                                <include>Report.avsc</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So `imports` section was missed.

P.S.
To fix it for pulled schemas in the `imports` section (and `includes` also) should be files from pulled folder.